# Cast ListView selected item tag to guid

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a `ListView` that contains data from a SQL database, I used the tag value from a `ListView` item to store an `uniqueid` from the database in (so I don't have to make an extra hidden column in the `ListView` to store it).

I am getting the following error:

> *System.InvalidCastException occurred*

and this is my code:

```
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE ID = @ID",     DBFactory.GetSqlConnection()))
{
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = ((Guid)listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag);

    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
    {
        sda.Fill(table);
    }
}
```

Any ideas / suggestions?

EDIT:
i found that the Type of listView1.SelectedItems.SelectedItemArray[0].Tag object {string} is.
Very strange because the DataType of the Column "ID" = UniqueIndentifier..

Comment: If you call `listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag.GetType().ToString()` what is the result? What about calling `listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag.ToString()`. This would help figure out how to cast/parse this value to a GUID.

Comment: What is type of listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag?

Comment: Try stepping through w/ the debugger and seeing what type of object listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag is.  You may need to parse the value into a GUID instead of casting it.

Comment: The value of listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag = 0197df7d-7a64-4e29-946d-c055bfca8e1b

If i try to get the type the temp var where im trying to store the type stays empty:

    var temp = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag.GetType().ToString();

Comment: @Chancho Try writing temp to the Console/Output Window/Message Box, it may be possible that if you are not using the temp variable it is getting optimized away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apearently the `listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag` is always a string, no matter what you store in it.

It's solved by changing the `SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier` to `SqlDbType.VarChar`

Comment: Just parse it using `new Guid(value)`, `Guid.Parse`, or `Guid.TryParse` and you won't have to change the DB schema

Comment: As @JGinSD says, I wouldn't store a GUID in a varchar field. Data integrity is important - that's why there are so many data types. I'd keep it a uniqueidentifier if you can.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to parse it as a GUID instead of casting it.

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value =
    (new Guid(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag));
```